# Home page title updated to fix a misspelling but Google still has the error

Tags: google, html, url, business

So recently I found that there was a misspelling on the URL title for my business in the google search and I fixed it within WordPress but it has updated on google yet, there is still that error. Does it take time to change within google or do I need to fix something else? [image]

As you can see in the picture - it should say "Simply Stated Hair Studio" not State

Comment: You just have to wait for Google to recrawl your page and update their index. Unfortunately it isn't always quick.

Comment: The Google index for the search term has now been updated, so this question seems to have answered itself.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with John Conde and yes it may take some time. Once Google crawls your site it will cache and index your pages in order to return the results quickly. So, it doesn't want to update the cache of billions of pages too often.

There are some suggestions that Google has provided to *hint* to its crawlers to recrawl and reindex the site that may help. [Ask Google to recrawl your URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en)

However, best bet is to just be patient, which can be hard sometimes.